# couchbase configuration on docker

Tags: docker, couchbase

Hello I am very new on Docker and I want to make some initial configuration in the couchbase like that:

Create a bucket

Set admin password

I want to automate these two process. Because: 
When I first run couchbase-db on docker (docker-compose up -d couchbase db) I am going localhost:8091 and I am setting admin password. If I didnt do this when first running, I could not run couchbase properly.

What are ways to do this? Is there any images for doing this? Can I change Docker file for initial configuration?

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide more informations about what you have done so far and what exactly you want to do.

Comment: OK I edit it, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Running Couchbase inside Docker container is quite trivial. You just need to run below command and you are done. And, yes as you mentioned once below command is run just launch url and configure the Boubhbase through web console.

```
$sudo docker run -d --name cb1 couchbase
```

Above command runs Couchbase in detached mode (-d) and name is cb1.

I have provided more details about it on my blog, [here](http://geekrai.blogspot.in/2017/03/create-couchbase-cluster-using-docker.html).

Answer (score 0):

I have been searching myself and have struck gold, I'd like to share it here for the record.

There is indeed an image for what the OP seeks to do: pre-configure server when the container is created.

This method uses the Couchbase API in a custom image that runs this shell script to setup the server and any worker nodes, if needed.
Here's an example to set credentials:

```
curl -v http://127.0.0.1:8091/settings/web -d port=8091 -d username=Administrator -d password=password
```

https://github.com/arun-gupta/docker-images/blob/master/couchbase/configure-node.sh

Here's how to use the image with docker-compose
https://github.com/arun-gupta/docker-images/tree/master/couchbase

After the image is pulled, modify the configure-node.sh to fit your needs. Then run in single or in swarm mode.

Sources:
https://blog.couchbase.com/couchbase-using-docker-compose/
https://docs.couchbase.com/server/4.0/rest-api/rest-bucket-create.html