# Couchbase docker entrypoint with cluster config

Tags: bash, docker, couchbase

I'm looking for a way to start couchbase (6.0.3) in docker and then as soon as it is ready, run a known-good couchbase-cli command (see below) to setup the cluster without me needing to do anything more than run the container.

```
couchbase-cli cluster-init --cluster "couchbase://127.0.0.1" --cluster-name "couchbase" --cluster-username "admin" --cluster-password "password" --services "data,index,query" --cluster-ramsize 500 --cluster-index-ramsize 256 --index-storage-setting "memopt";
```

So far I tried to solve this using docker-compose's `command` keyword as shown below

```
version: '2.4'

services:
  couchbase:
    image: couchbase:6.0.3
    container_name: "couchbase"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8091-8094:8091-8094
      - 11210:11210
    command: >
      /bin/bash -c "
        until curl -I -s http://localhost:8091/ui/index.html
        do
            echo 'Waiting for Couchbase to start (retrying in 3 seconds)...'
            sleep 3
        done
        couchbase-cli cluster-init --cluster "couchbase://127.0.0.1" --cluster-name "couchbase" --cluster-username "admin" --cluster-password "password" --services "data,index,query" --cluster-ramsize 500 --cluster-index-ramsize 256 --index-storage-setting "memopt"
      "
```

This resulted in a seemingly endless loop of printing `Waiting for Couchbase to start (retrying in 3 seconds)...` with couchbase not accessible on localhost:8091.

I then changed tactic and decided to create my own Dockerfile based on the couchbase image, changing the entrypoint to incorporate the couchbase-cli command as follows

Dockerfile:

```
FROM couchbase:6.0.3
RUN mkdir files
COPY initcouchbase.sh files/
RUN chmod +x files/initcouchbase.sh
ENTRYPOINT ./files/initcouchbase.sh
```

initcouchbase.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

/entrypoint.sh couchbase-server &

until curl -I -s http://localhost:8091/ui/index.html
do
    echo 'Waiting for Couchbase to start (retrying in 3 seconds)...'
    sleep 3
done

couchbase-cli cluster-init --cluster "couchbase://127.0.0.1" --cluster-name "couchbase" --cluster-username "admin" --cluster-password "password" --services "data,index,query" --cluster-ramsize 500 --cluster-index-ramsize 256 --index-storage-setting "memopt"
```

This sort of works, in that when the docker logs show that the cluster has been configured with the cli-command success message (`SUCCESS: Cluster initialized`) for a few moments it is possible to login to the local cluster. However, a moment later something decides to run again (I'm assuming the entirety of `initcouchbase.sh` is run over and over again), which renders couchbase unavailable again for a few seconds until the loop completes each time.

Has anyone attempted this as well and conquered it? I can't see much content on this particular use case on here apart from the one linked below but the answer doesn't cover the points of my question.

[couchbase configuration on docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38993026/couchbase-configuration-on-docker)

Comment: Assuming this is for a development environment, are you familiar with wait-for-it.sh? https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it - or another tool might be couchbasefakeit docker image - https://github.com/brantburnett/couchbasefakeit